# Injectivity of one-parameter group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, group-theory

I need to prove that every element of the one-parameter group of transformations is injective.

The one-parameter group is defined as the family $\{g^t\}$ of mappings of a set $M$ into itself where $$g^{t+s} = g^tg^s$$ for all $s, t\in \Bbb R$ and $g^0$ is the identity mapping.

I've already proven this is an Abelian group.  I don't see how to prove injectivity, though.

To prove injectivity I need to prove that $g^tx = g^ty \implies x=y$.  Usually to do this I plug in whatever $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are and do some algebra until I get $x=y$.  But I don't have anything to plug in here.  How am I supposed to prove these functions are injective?

Comment: try applying $g^{-t}$ and see what happens

Comment: Hah.  So simple! Thanks. :)